# Static cast in middle of inheritance chain

Tags: c++, casting

Suppose we have:

```
class Component : public QGraphicsItem {
   ...
   virtual void paintMe() = 0;
   virtual void doSomething();

   virtual bool isComposite() const { return false; }
}

class Composite: public Component {
   ...
   void addChildren(Component *);
   void removeChildren(Component *)

   bool isComposite() const { return true; }
}

class IconNode: public Composite {
  ...
  void paintMe();
}

class ImageNode: public Composite {
  ...
  void paintMe();
}
```

The question is: Is following example safe, if I can guarantee that *item* is **always** some class that inherits *Composite*?

```
void test (Component *item) {
  if (item.isComposite()) {
    Composite *comp = static_cast<Composite*>(item);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I know that this is a little bit strange example, since I could use dynamic_cast for safety, but I was wondering if it can be done with static_cast.

**Background:**
I am having troubles with Qt Graphics View Framework. Namely, it has functions T qgraphicsitem_cast ( QGraphicsItem * item ) which casts items to original class (e.g.  IconNode -> IconNode, Compsite -> Composite), but it can't cast to class in the middle of inheritance chain (IconNode -> Composite) since it recognizes the classes by using function type() and because type() for IconNode and Composite is different the conversion fails.

This can be solved by following example, but I am wondering if my previous example could do the job safely:

```
Composite * castItem (QGraphicsItem *item) {
  if (item != 0) {
    switch(item.type()) {
      case IconNode::Type:
        return qgraphicsitem_cast<IconNode*>(item);
      case ImageNode::Type:
        return qgraphcisitem_cast<ImageNode*>(item);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "last class in inheritance chain"? the most derived?

Comment: Yes. The example are classes IconNode and ImageNode. None of classes inherits them.

Comment: ah! i finally understand the question. basically the **background** part is not really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: yes, if you know it is something, you can `static_cast` to it safely.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast` is pretty much just

1. check type for compatibility
2. use `static_cast` if ok, `return null`/`throw badcast` otherwise

Comment: So I guess since I can do the **1.**, using static_cast would be safe?

Comment: Yeah, if you already checked, then you can safely use `static_cast`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You're very much oversimplifying and underestimating dynamic_cast. No static_cast can deal with multiple inheritance, neither can it be used for sibling casts

Comment: @Armen Well `Sibling * s = static_cast<Top*>(me);` should work just fine (if it is valid of course) and I'm not sure right now what the issue with multiple inheritance is.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: See this example: http://pastebin.com/WWhw7GAY static_cast won't even compile here. Despite what you might think from the random link, the example is not GAY lol

Comment: @Armen Because the equivalent isn't `static_cast<A&>`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Which is the equivalent then?

Comment: @Armen `static_cast<C&>` of course, that is what dynamic cast does.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - Oh no, it doesn't. It does cast one brother to another brother if the brother was in fact the father.. something like that. You really should read more about dynamic_cast. It's more interesting than it seems

Comment: @Armen Yes it does cast brother to another brother but by basically doing `static_cast<Brother1&>(static_cast<TopClass&>(brother2))` The Brother1 cast can be skipped (cause it is implicit) and TopClass is determined dynamically and checked before casting.

Comment: Thank you all for answers! Just to help in discussion: I don't need to cast from brother to another brother and I don't use multiple inheritance except when I use one non-abstract class and several pure-abstract classes (interfaces). Under there circumstances could we all agree that static_cast in my example is safe to use?